# Fastest way to check for update using PHP,AJAX and MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

I need to check for updates on a (max) one second interval for updates.

I'm now looking for the fastest way to do that using AJAX for the requests and PHP and MySQL.

**Solution 1**
Every time new data, that needs to be retreived by other clients, is added to the MySQL database a file.txt is updated with 1. AJAX makes a request to a PHP file which will check if file.txt contains a 1 or 0. If it contains a 1 it will get the data from the MySQL database and return it to the client.

**Solution 2**
Every AJAX request calls a PHP file which will check directly into MySQL database for new data.

**Solution ..?**
If there is any faster solution i'd be happy to know! (considering I can only use PHP/MySQL and AJAX)

Comment: You might want to look at node.js if you're building a real-time app.

Comment: I know it's the best way, but I want to avoid node.js for this project.

Comment: The technology is quite new and still developed, but have you ever considered WebSockets for a full duplex communication between server and client?

Comment: If your ajax call returns json you can make php code that updates database to generate some json file which will be returned to ajax. there you can add last modification.
If your data is to large for this you can have separate php code that will generate static html code that will be returned when you make that ajax code. This will definitely reduce mysql time.
If you need to make calls that often it would be the best to ask for static data (not php script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoiding the database will probably not make the process significantly faster, if at all.

You can use a comet-style ajax request to get near real-time polling. Basically, create an ajax request as usual to a php-script, but on the server side you poll the database and sleep for a short interval if there is nothing new. Repeat until there is something of interest for the client. If nothing appears within a timeframe of e.g. 60 seconds, close the connection down. On the client side, you only open a new connection once the first has terminated (either with a response or as a timeout).

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)